# Why might I not be able to delete a file from an unextracted zip folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, compression, zip

I have a zip folder (40-50GB) that contains a set of data files and a single (1 KB) .ahk script. The .ahk script was used to unencrypt the data files in a folder before creating a zip of that folder that all of these files are now sitting in; the script contains the passphrase used to unlock the files. **I would like to delete the .ahk file from this zip folder without extracting the folder in order to do it** (ie. I'd like to do it by just double-clicking into the .zip in File Explorer and using the context menu to delete the .ahk file), since making these zips in the first pace takes a very long time because of the amount of data, but am getting an error when trying to do so: "An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting this file. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem. Error 0x80004005: Unspecified error"

What could be going on here?

The zip folders directory structure looks like...

```
My Folder
    |____ data_folder
          |____ <bunch of encrypted data files>
          |____ my_decrypting_script.ahk 
    |____ data_folder.zip
          |____ data_folder
                |____ <bunch of encrypted data files>
                |____ <bunch of decrypted data files>
                |____ my_decrypting_script.ahk    <---------- this is what I want to delete
```

The odd thing is that I was able to successfully delete these .ahk script from some other (slightly smaller) .zip folders I created in a similar way, but for other .zip folders I get this error. Why would this be?

*These zip folders were created by opening the File Explorer context menu on the original data folder, then clicking "Send To" > "Compressed (zipped) folder".

Comment: Considered using a 3rd party utility to handle the ZIP file? 7-Zip, WinRAR, or something like them, they are in general much better than Windows Explorer at handling archives.

Comment: To note, I don't think that "deleting" a file from a ZIP means simply that, in the background it is basically recreating the ZIP without the file, so it would/should take long anyway.